# PowerBi importing more rows than expected from SSAS

Tags: powerbi, ssas

As per the title, I have a test tabular cube deployed to SSAS. The model itself is very small, only about 2mb in size, however when I try to import it to PowerBI it's throwing an out of memory exception. The model itself only has a few thousand rows.

Why is PowerBi using up so much memory for such a small import? It's eating up the RAM on the machine and then throwing an exception.

Comment: Hi, It might be some time due to 32-bit version I would suggest update 64 bit and try.

Comment: I'll have to put in a request as this is for my work machine which I do not have full access to, thanks though will try.

Comment: @RajatJaiswal I just checked and it is in fact 64 bit.

Comment: Don't import it into tabular, use live connection, it's trying to flatten your data model.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, would you mind explaining a bit more what the power bi engine does when importing an ssas cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling this problem gave a few results:

Here https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Not-Enough-Memory-Error/td-p/193818 it's described that memory issues in the SSAS server might cause similar problems.

Here https://mydataodyssey.blogspot.com/2019/03/power-bi-olap-import.html is a blogpost describing how Power BI creates as unefficient query to the SSAS cube, which might cause memory issues.

As @Jon said, with SSAS tabular cubes, it's best to use Live Connection instead of import.